# Error when frequently querying with hibernate envers

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp, audit, hibernate-envers

I have the following query:

```
 List results2 = AuditReaderFactory.get( factory.createEntityManager() ).createQuery()
        .forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges( Customer.class, false )
        .add( AuditEntity.id().eq( 3014l ) )
        .getResultList();
```

When I run these lines frequently (approximately once every two seconds and always waiting for complete execution), then after the fifth or sixth time, I get error:

```
2020-12-15 22:57:46.320  WARN 41949 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2020-12-15 22:57:46.320 ERROR 41949 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30004ms.
2020-12-15 22:57:46.339 ERROR 41949 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause

java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30004ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:669) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:183) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
....
```